# lag function over multiple rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, lag

I have a table like this

```
b.b_id fp.fp_id b.name
1      10       Dan
1
1
1
2      15       Michelle
2
3      20       Steve
3
3
```

Im trying to get this output

```
b.b_id fp.fp_id b.name
1      10       Dan
1               Dan
1               Dan
1               Dan
2      15       Michelle
2               Michelle
3      20       Steve
3               Steve
3               Steve
```

My idea was using the lag function but with this code i am only able to fill 1 row below.

```
select b.b_id,fp.fp_id,
case 
    when fp.fp_id is null then lag(b.name,1) over (partition by b.b_id order by b.b_id,fp.fp_id) 
    else b.name 
end as name 
from  b 
left join  fp on fp.id = b.fp_id
```

Output at the moment

```
b.b_id fp.fp_id b.name
1      10       Dan
1               Dan
1
1
2      15       Michelle
2               Michelle
3      20       Steve
3               Steve
3
```

Is there some easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE temp TABLE test101 (
    id bigint,
    fp_id bigint,
    name text
);

INSERT INTO test101
    VALUES (1, 10, 'dan'),
    (1, NULL, NULL),
    (1, NULL, NULL),
    (1, NULL, NULL),
    (2, 15, 'Michelle'),
    (2, NULL, NULL),
    (3, 20, 'Steve'),
    (3, NULL, NULL),
    (3, NULL, NULL);

SELECT
    id,
    fp_id,
    first_value(name) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC nulls LAST, fp_id NULLS LAST)
FROM
    test101;
```